# Android edtftpj/PRo SFTP heap worker

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, sftp, edtftpj

I am using `edtftpj-pro3.1` trial copy in my android app to make SFTP connection with the server. After few connections with the server with 5-6 file transfers, my app is crashing with following exception. Is it causing the problem or what could be the problem??

I tried `setParallelMode(false)` in `SSHFTPClient`, but it is not working.

Exception i'm getting is,

```
05-31 18:28:12.661: ERROR/dalvikvm(589): HeapWorker is wedged: 10173ms spent inside Lcom/enterprisedt/net/j2ssh/sftp/SftpFileInputStream;.finalize()V
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): DALVIK THREADS:
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "main" prio=5 tid=3 WAIT
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b260 self=0xbd18
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=589 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1343993192
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): - waiting on <0x122d70> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-31 18:28:12.661: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Transport protocol 1" daemon prio=5 tid=29 NATIVE
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44774768 self=0x3a7938
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=605 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3834600
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStreamImpl(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStream(OSNetworkSystem.java:478)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:565)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:87)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:67)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:157)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:346)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:341)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.A.A((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.A.B((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.processMessages((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.startBinaryPacketProtocol((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.run((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "StreamFrameSender" prio=5 tid=27 TIMED_WAIT
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44750a60 self=0x3964d8
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=603 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3761648
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): - waiting on <0x399478> (a com.corventis.gateway.ppp.StreamFrameSender)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.ppp.StreamFrameSender.run(StreamFrameSender.java:154)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.util.MonitoredRunnable.run(MonitoredRunnable.java:41)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "SftpActiveWorker" prio=5 tid=25 TIMED_WAIT
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x447522b0 self=0x398e00
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=604 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3762704
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): - waiting on <0x3962d8> (a com.corventis.gateway.hostcommunicator.SftpActiveWorker)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hostcommunicator.SftpActiveWorker.run(SftpActiveWorker.java:151)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.util.MonitoredRunnable.run(MonitoredRunnable.java:41)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Thread-12" prio=5 tid=23 NATIVE
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4474aca8 self=0x115690
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=602 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=878120
05-31 18:28:12.671: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.acceptNative(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:287)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:105)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:91)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.bluetooth.BluetoothManager.openPort(BluetoothManager.java:215)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.bluetooth.BluetoothManager.open(BluetoothManager.java:84)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.patchcommunicator.PatchCommunicator.open(PatchCommunicator.java:123)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.patchcommunicator.PatchCommunicatorRunnable.run(PatchCommunicatorRunnable.java:134)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "HfGatewayApplication" prio=5 tid=21 RUNNABLE
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4472d9b0 self=0x120928
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=601 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1264672
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.jcraft.jzlib.Deflate.deflateInit2(Deflate.java:~1361)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.jcraft.jzlib.Deflate.deflateInit(Deflate.java:1316)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.jcraft.jzlib.ZStream.deflateInit(ZStream.java:127)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.jcraft.jzlib.ZStream.deflateInit(ZStream.java:120)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.jcraft.jzlib.ZOutputStream.<init>(ZOutputStream.java:62)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.zipfile.ZipStorer.addStream(ZipStorer.java:211)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.zipfile.ZipStorer.createZip(ZipStorer.java:127)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hostcommunicator.HostCommunicator.scanAndCompress(HostCommunicator.java:453)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hostcommunicator.HostCommunicator.doWork(HostCommunicator.java:1434)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hf.HfGatewayApplication.doWork(HfGatewayApplication.java:621)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hf.HfGatewayApplication.run(HfGatewayApplication.java:546)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.util.MonitoredRunnable.run(MonitoredRunnable.java:41)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=19 TIMED_WAIT
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x447287f8 self=0x1451b8
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=598 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1331920
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1306)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1286)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.util.Watchdog.run(Watchdog.java:167)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Thread-9" prio=5 tid=17 RUNNABLE
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=Y obj=0x44722c90 self=0x114e20
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=597 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1200048
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.time.Time.currentTimeMillis(Time.java:~77)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.patchcommunicator.PatchCommunicatorState$1.run(PatchCommunicatorState.java:27)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Thread-8" prio=5 tid=15 RUNNABLE
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=Y obj=0x44722430 self=0x124dd0
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=596 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1199848
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.time.Time.currentTimeMillis(Time.java:~80)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.corventis.gateway.hostcommunicator.HostCommunicatorState$1.run(HostCommunicatorState.java:35)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4471ccc0 self=0x149b60
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=595 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1317992
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x447159a8 self=0x123298
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=594 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1164896
05-31 18:28:12.681: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=9 VMWAIT
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4470f2a0 self=0x141a90
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=593 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1316864
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7 VMWAIT
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4470f1e8 self=0x124970
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=592 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1316800
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): "HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=5 MONITOR
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x431b4550 self=0x141670
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): | sysTid=591 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1316400
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.closeHandle((null):~-1)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.closeFile((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpFile.close((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpFileInputStream.close((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpFileInputStream.finalize((null):-1)
05-31 18:28:12.691: INFO/dalvikvm(589): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-31 18:28:12.691: ERROR/dalvikvm(589): VM aborting
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): Build fingerprint: 'google/passion/passion/mahimahi:2.1-update1/ERE27/24178:user/release-keys'
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): pid: 589, tid: 601 >>> com.corventis.gateway.hf <<<
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): r0 00000026 r1 afe13329 r2 afe13329 r3 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): r4 ad081f50 r5 400091e8 r6 009b3a6a r7 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): r8 000002e8 r9 ad082ba0 10 ad082ba0 fp 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.801: INFO/DEBUG(49): ip deadd00d sp 46937c58 lr afe14373 pc ad035b4c cpsr 20000030
05-31 18:28:12.851: INFO/DEBUG(49): #00 pc 00035b4c /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #01 pc 00044d7c /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #02 pc 000162e4 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #03 pc 00016b60 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #04 pc 00016ce0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #05 pc 00057b64 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.861: INFO/DEBUG(49): #06 pc 00057cc0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #07 pc 00057dd4 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #08 pc 00012ffc /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #09 pc 00019338 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #10 pc 00018804 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #11 pc 0004eed0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #12 pc 0004eef8 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.871: INFO/DEBUG(49): #13 pc 000426d4 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): #14 pc 0000fd74 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): #15 pc 0000f840 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): code around pc:
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): ad035b3c 58234808 b1036b9b f8df4798 2026c01c
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): ad035b4c 0000f88c ef52f7d8 0004c428 fffe631c
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): ad035b5c fffe94f4 000002f8 deadd00d f8dfb40e
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): code around lr:
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): afe14360 686768a5 f9b5e008 b120000c 46289201
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): afe14370 9a014790 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f3
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): afe14380 d1ed2c00 bdfe4630 00026ab0 000000b4
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): stack:
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c18 00000015
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c1c afe13359 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.881: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c20 afe3b02c /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c24 afe3afd8 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c28 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c2c afe14373 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c30 afe13329 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c34 afe13329 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c38 afe13380 /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c3c ad081f50 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c40 400091e8 /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c44 009b3a6a
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c48 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c4c afe1338d /system/lib/libc.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c50 df002777
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c54 e3a070ad
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): #00 46937c58 ad06f573 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c5c ad044d81 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): #01 46937c60 000027bd
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c64 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c68 463b6ab4 /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.corventis.gateway.hf.apk@classes.dex
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c6c 463d1ecf /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.corventis.gateway.hf.apk@classes.dex
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c70 00140450 [heap]
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c74 ad041d2b /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c78 ad082f2c /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c7c ad06826c /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c80 00140450 [heap]
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c84 00000000
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c88 000002f8
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c8c 400091e8 /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c90 ad081f50 /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c94 000002f8
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c98 00002710
05-31 18:28:12.891: INFO/DEBUG(49): 46937c9c ad0162e8 /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above, this fix is in [edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html) 3.4.0, out now.